# How to index into a list until a specific data type is encountered?

Tags: python

I have a list, `L`.  `L` may contain other lists inside it.  These other lists may also contain lists.  At some point, the indexing will return an int value.  How do I make a function that returns the first encountered int value?

```
L = [[[1,2,3],[4,5]],[6,7]]
```

As you can see, L can have lists of lists until some arbitrary endpoint, of which I am unaware.  I tried first doing hardcoded `if` loops such as:

```
if isinstance(L[0],int): return L[0]
elif isinstance(L[0][0],int): return L[0][0]
... #and so on
```

But this feels unPythonic and wrong.

Is there a built-in function or other methodology for solving this problem?

Comment: Write a recursive function.

Comment: What exactly is the desired result for your sample list?

Comment: Flatten the list, then return the first element of the result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists for how to flatten the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Barmar in the comments, you could write a recursive function (the problem itself is a classical use case for recursion).  However, you could equally use a `while` loop.

Recursive version:

```py
def first(L):
    if isinstance(L, list):
        return first(L[0])
    else:
        return L
```

Version with `while`-loop:

```py
def first(L):
    while isinstance(L, list):
        L = L[0]
    return L
```

Instead of using `isinstance`, you can also use a `try`-block instead:

```py
def first(L):
    try:
        while True:
            L = L[0]
    except:
        return L
```

A last variant would use iteration instead of subscripts like so:

```py
def first(L):
    try:
        while True:
            L, *_ = L
    except:
        return L
```

Comparing the running times of these variants, I get:

- Recursive function: 0.462
- While and `isinstance`: 0.355
- While and `try`: 0.319
- While and iter: 0.567

So, using a `while`-loop with a `try`-block is the fastest solution.  And it has the nice added benefit that it also just works out of the box with tuples instead of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple loop:

```
my_elem = L[0]

while not isinstance(my_elem, int):
    my_elem = my_elem[0]
```

This is the nice part of a dynamically typed language: you can always put an `int` in to the same variable you were putting lists before